# Creating beastmen as a Lunar

Tags: exalted-3e

How does Lunar make beastmen? Are there any charm or sorcery to help them do so in 3e?

I think I read something about this in a earlier edition, but can't find it in any of the books I have. Though I'm mostly interested in 3e I would also appreciate a reference to earlier edition of they have more or better information about this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three ways a Lunar can create a beastman, or maybe more accurately described as a mortal with animalistic mutations. In addition, there is a way to make minor alterations that might in some way qualify.

**Testing Ground**

Using the charm Beast-Soul Awakening Crucible p205 the Lunar creates a testing ground. Mortals entering this testing ground and subsequently pass the test will emerge with animalistic mutations reflecting the Lunar's own hybrid form. A Lunar with multiple hybrid forms can make beastmen reflecting either or even let the testing ground select the best fit for each mortal that passes the test.

**Mating in hybrid form**

Lunars mating in hybrid form will pass on their own mutations to their offspring.

Lunars Fangs at the Gate p60

> Lunars can create beastfolk, most notably by using Beast-Soul
> Awakening Crucible (p. 205) to create sacred testing grounds that
> transform those who overcome their trials into beastfolk. Any child a
> Lunar sires or conceives while using Hybrid Body Transformation (p.
> 143) inherits her parent’s animalistic mutations.

**Sharing Luna’s Gifts**

Using this charm available to Lunars they can mutate willing individual subjects.

Lunars Fangs at the Gate p204
She grants a willing character up to five dots of mutations reflect- ing an animal whose shape she possesses.

**Flesh-Sculpting Art**

This charm to a lesser extent allow creation of beastmen, but specifically will not grant the signature animalistic mutations.

Lunars Fangs at the Gate p200

> Additionally, the Lunar may perform surgeries beyond mundane medicine’s limits in the Age of Sorrows — making cosmetic alterations to a patient’s body, hol- lowing out pouches of flesh to smuggle contraband or sealing them up, etc. She can’t grant mutations.